# Detect IDE environment with Gradle

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

Is there anyway to detect the environment I'm running my project.

Something like this:

build.gradle

```
def usingIntelliJ = ...
def usingAndroidStudio = ...
if (usingIntelliJ) {
    buildConfigField "String", "IDE_ENV", "IDEA"
} else if (usingAndroidStudio) {
    buildConfigField "String", "IDE_ENV", "AndroidStudio"
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want different behavior in Java based upon your IDE?

Comment: I'm doing unit test using gradle and robolectric-gradle-plugin. The test run file when I execute command `gradle clean test`. However, when I run my test with IntelliJ, it does not work. Turn out that `System.getProperty("android.manifest")` is null if I run it on IntelliJ. So I know that the test is running with IntelliJ, I will set the property `android.manifest` myself.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just set that property for all cases? Will setting that property break tests run outside of IntelliJ? I'm not ruling out that there's a way to detect the environment that triggered your Gradle build, but my guess is that it will be a fragile solution at best.

Comment: By running `gradle clean test`, `("android.manifest")` will be set by robolectric-gradle-plugin. I figured out that when I run the test using IntelliJ, this property is not set. So I would like the IDE to do whatever `gradle test` does, or if the IDE can't do so, I will have to set that property manually. And yes, by doing it manually, it should work for even outside of IntelliJ, I'm just wondering ...

Comment: I need the same but because of different reason. I have special method App.isIDEBuild() in my app that allow me to setup special debug stuff, like prefill login screen with passwords, skip some screens to speed up development. But if app is builded from commandline (on CI server), it must work as ussual. So it is much better to use App.isIDEBuild() than change code itself and forgot remove something.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think I found a use case where it is desired to find out if we're running from an IDE - Instant Run! :)

Comment: @CommonsWare Another use case is when the IDE has a bug that you want to work around, but the workaround breaks the build when run from the command-line.

Answer (score 9):

To determine if your build is triggered by an IDE, the Android build chain will set a specific property:

```
def isIdeBuild() {
    return project.properties['android.injected.invoked.from.ide'] == 'true'
}
```

In our builds we use this method to set a static `versionCode` for our IDE builds, but keep the desired behavior to automatically increase it on our build servers:

```
def getNumberOfGitCommits() {
    def text = 'git rev-list --count HEAD'.execute().text.trim()
    return text == '' ? 0 : text.toInteger()
}

def calculateVersionCode() {
    return isIdeBuild() ? 123456789 : getNumberOfGitCommits()
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        versionCode calculateVersionCode()
    }
}
```

This solved two problems we had:

1. Before, new commits effectively disabled Instant Run. Because the `versionCode` was updated automatically, the Manifest was changed – which triggers a full rebuild in Instant Run.
2. Before, when we switched Git branches, the `versionCode` often changed to a smaller one (downgrade), so we had to re-install the app. Now we have the same versionCode for all our IDE builds.

Comment: This property seems to no longer be set by my version of IDEA. Did it stop working for you @mreichelt? If so, did you find an alternative?

Comment: @TomClift Still works for me with latest Android Studio 2.3 and Android Studio 3.0 Canary 7. Google itself uses this property in their latest architecture components samples: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/build.gradle#L32

Which version of IDEA are you using? Maybe this property only exists in Android Studio, not IDEA. Then you have to find a different one that is set by IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. Not sure when it stopped working. Tested not working on 2017.1.5 and 2017.2. Came up with alternative (without a good grasp of which ones work with which products/versions):
`ideIdea = System.env.XPC_SERVICE_NAME.contains('intellij') || System.env.XPC_SERVICE_NAME.contains('.idea') ||
 (project.findProperty('android.injected.invoked.from.ide') ?: false) || project.hasProperty('jetExtraModelBuilderClass')`
One example of XPC_SERVICE_NAME is `com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000001.idea`.

Comment: This property seems to be present only when running from Intellij:

`if (System.env.IDEA_INITIAL_DIRECTORY == null) {...`

Comment: It only works if you have the Android plugin installed.  That is present always with Android Studio but is optional with Intellij.  I just removed the Android plugin and this stopped working.

Answer (score 6):

In build script you can evaluate following properties which IDE adds:

- `idea.active` property that IDE sets when you run Gradle tasks from IDE;
- `idea.sync.active` property which is added by IDE when IDE [reloads project from Gradle build scripts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#gradle_refresh_project).

For example: `System.getProperty('idea.active')`.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not work for me, but by looking at all the properties, these seem to work:

- `idea.paths.selector` - in default instalations, this has a value such as "AndroidStudioPreview2021.1" or "IntelliJIdea2021.2", so you could use this if you needed to know if it was either:

```
def pathSelector = System.getProperty('idea.paths.selector') ?: ''
def usingIntelliJ = pathSelector.startsWith('IntelliJIdea')
def usingAndroidStudio = pathSelector.startsWith('AndroidStudio')
...
```

- `idea.platform.prefix` - which seems to only be set for Android Studio, with a value of "AndroidStudio", so it may not work for this case but was the solution to mine:

```
def usingAndroidStudio = System.getProperty('idea.platform.prefix') == 'AndroidStudio'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check one or more of the following system properties:

```
System.getProperty("idea.platform.prefix") -> AndroidStudio


idea.home.path -> /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents 
idea.paths.selector -> AndroidStudio2021.2 
idea.popup.weight -> heavy 
idea.version -> 2021.2 
idea.xdebug.key -> -Xdebug 
idea.jre.check -> true 
idea.executable -> studio 
idea.platform.prefix -> AndroidStudio  
idea.active -> true 
idea.vendor.name -> Google 
idea.no.launcher -> false 
idea.cycle.buffer.size -> 1024 
idea.max.intellisense.filesize -> 2500 
idea.dynamic.classpath -> false 
idea.max.content.load.filesize -> 20000
```